# Does noise match of an LNA mean minimum signal to noise ratio at output?

Tags: rf, analog, noise

Does noise match of an LNA means minimum signal to noise ratio at output? According to definition it means minimizing relative contribution of noise power with respect to source.

If not why do we then do noise match at input of LNA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means maximum SNR for the LNA stage. This, however, decreases the gain i.e. you need more stages. Since the contribution of the first stage is the most important one, and the NF for each stage is divided by the gain of the previous stages, it is sometimes better to decrease the total number of stages instead of maximizing the SNR.

In some applications you try to maximize the SNR e.g. satellite communications when you have pushed the channel SNR close to the limits. This means that you need more amplifiers, but you cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

One does careful matching on the input side of the LNA because that figure will swamp all of the others in a system.  You could carefully apply the same techniques, in theory, to each amplifier through the signal chain, but to what gain?